# JFace wizard: about the getNextPage methods

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, wizard

i am creating right now a jface wizard and wondering about those `getNextPage()` methods.
There a two of them. One in the `Wizard` class and one in the `WizardPage` class.

The `getNextPage()` method in the `WizardPage` is the event for the next button.
The `getNextPage(IWizardPage page)` method in the `Wizard` is for controlling the page order.

**First try:**
When i use both methods, only the `getNextPage()` of the `WizardPage` getting called.
Well its stupid to control the page orders in the page-classes. (modifiers..) but i have a event on my next button.

**Second try:**
When i only use the `getNextPage(IWizardPage page)` of the `Wizard` class i can control the page order easy but i don't have an event on my next button, so i cannot collect all my information from the current page.

How does this all fit together and is there a seperate way to solve this?!

Best regards!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I don't understand why there are 2 methods and which of them i should use. Or do i need to use both? And if yes, what sense does it make if the `public IWizardPage getNextPage()` method in the `WizardPage` class returns a `IWizardPage` and the `public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage iwizardpage)` of the `Wizard` class returns also a `IWizardPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `WizardPage.getNextPage()` just calls `Wizard.getNextPage(this)` so if you override it you should call `super.getNextPage()`.

If you want to know when the wizard page becomes visible override `setVisible(boolean visible)` in the WizardPage (actually a `DialogPage` member).

Comment: sry i forgot to answer you.. your first statement was that i was searching for! :) thanks